# webpack export external plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to export a library (called dlmenu https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Responsive-Multi-Level-Menu-Plugin-Dlmenu.html ) as a variable so it can be bundled with other plugins. I have installed bootstrap with webpack, but I get an error if I try to export this library.

```
// main.js file

const css = require('../stylesheets/styles.scss');
var $ = require('jquery'); //  importing jquery works
var JQuery = require('jquery'); // same here.
require('bootstrap'); // bootstrap works
require('slick-carousel'); //the carousel plugin works 
require('./jquery.dlmenu.js'); // error if i export this pugin
```

The webpack error is :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined

     at eval (webpack-internal:///7:15)
     at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///7:15)
     at eval (webpack-internal:///7:257)
     at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:153)
     at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
     at eval (webpack-internal:///1:4)
     at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:86)
     at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
     at bundle.js:63
     at bundle.js:66
```

Comment: I dont see jquery import. I quess it is dependency of jquery.dl.menu.sj

Comment: @bigless yes even i even exported $ and JQuery but still get the same error.